# Extraction of tables from PDF

Tags: python, r, pdf, pdf-scraping

I have a pdf file containing **text, images and tables**.I want to extract just the tables from that pdf file using either Python or R.

Comment: [Okay](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Asking auntie [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=R+extract+pdf+data&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=kn1tWvTjF46g4gTm06q4Bw) helps

Answer (score 2):

If you are considering using **R** I would recommend using the tabulizer package.
it is available [here](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer) and is very easy to use.
to install it you would have to use the following command:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer")
```

And using one of their examples:

```
library("tabulizer")
f <- system.file("examples", "data.pdf", package = "tabulizer")
# When f is your selected pdf file.
out1 <- extract_tables(f)
# Or even better, say what page the tables are in.
out2 <- extract_tables(f, pages = 1, guess = FALSE, method = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find PyPI useful - you can search for specific things on there like 'PDF' and it will give you a list of modules relating to PDF's ([here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=PDF&submit=search)).  You'll probably want PDF 1.0 judging from it's weight on PyPI.  This should help you get started!